# how to redirect with htaccess to a subdirectory but dont show the folder in url (drupal 7)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, drupal-7

(There are very similar questions but none of that solved it)

1. My domain is www.abc.com this is automaticly mapped to /public_html (made by my hoster, i can't change in admin panel)
2. My cms drupal7.15 is in folder public_html/foo/drupal715/

Big question:
**WHY: When i open www.abc.com, the url looks www.abc.com/foo/drupal715/index.php**
It should be the same! BUT the other links or pages i created with drupal are working e.g www.abc.com/myproject

Look at my configuration

I have the first .htaccess in root (public_html) which looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abc.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.ch$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/drupal715/$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

This redirects to my sub dir works but why the url shows the folder when i open my main url ?

Any help, please! im so tired of trying.

Here the intresting part of the htaccess in drupal root.

```
 # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line
  #RewriteBase /foo/drupal715
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /

  # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
  # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/foo/drupal715/(.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,B]
  #RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way mod_rewrite works is explained in the docs and discussed many times here too.
It works on the server, it does **NOT** (unless you specifically make a rule to do this) return any changed urls to the client. This is what allows you to create and use "user friendly urls". If your site redirect from one page/folder to another I would suggest you start looking at what is actually being requested and what it actually does. For example - look at your index.php, what does **it** do?